# How can I read google-cloud-storage file's metadata from BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, metadata, bq

I have a csv file in my google-cloud storage and I have some custom meta-data on this file. I want to read this metadata from my BigQuery. Is this possible. If so please let me know how this should be done.

Comment: Why do you need to access to the metadata. What do you want to do with?

Answer (score 1):

With BigQuery, it's not possible to query external API. You can only process data reachable by bigquery (native table, google drive files, GCS files, BigTable tables and Cloud SQL request) and not perform API call, for example to get the file metadata.

You can only know the [file name](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column), not more.